# Android : Inform adapter that data-set has changed from a static method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android project in which I am trying to integrate `PUSH` service offered by [Cometd](http://www.cometd.org) framework.
Now, whenever a new message arrives for a `Conversation`, I would like to inform `ChatMessagesActivity` which contains the list of messages between the two users.

Now, when the other user sends a message to the Android app, I would like to update the view of the user. I tried doing that by calling `notifyDataSetHasChanged()` on the `adapter`, but because I was calling it outside of `View` thread, I am getting an error.

The method is static, because new messages are received in `Conversation` class, while the messages are going-on in `ChatMessagesActivity` class. For communication between both classes, I have created 2 static methods which act like a bi-directional bridge for sending & receiving messages.

I hope I was clear, if there are any doubts, kindly let me know.

ChatMessagesActivity.java :

```
public class ChatMessagesActivity extends ApplicationDrawerLoader {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_messages);

        chatList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chatList);

 new getPrivateChatsForUser(this).execute();

}

// IN the method below, I receive information from another activity.

    public static void recieveUpdatedMessage(String channelName, Map<String, Object> input){
 Boolean found = Arrays.asList(channelName.split(" ")).contains("chat");
        if(found){
            int processedChannelName = Integer.valueOf(channelName.replace("/chat/",""));
            if(processedChannelName == groupAccountId){

// Here i tried calling adapter.NotifyDataSetchanged();.. Didn't fly.

            }
        }
}

// Async method retrieving messages.
    public class getPrivateChatsForUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResponseEntity<RestReplies[]>> {

        ChatMessagesActivity chatMessagesActivity = null;

        getPrivateChatsForUser(ChatMessagesActivity chatMessagesActivity) {
            this.chatMessagesActivity = chatMessagesActivity;
        }
 @Override
        protected ResponseEntity<RestReplies[]> doInBackground(Void... params) { 
// network connection related stuff, not relevant to problem
}
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<RestReplies[]> responseEntity) {
            super.onPostExecute(responseEntity);
            RestReplies[] restRepliesArray = responseEntity.getBody();
            Collections.addAll(restRepliesList, restRepliesArray);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> chatMessagesHashMapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (RestReplies restReplies : restRepliesList) {
                HashMap<String, String> chatMap = new HashMap<>();
                chatMap.put(chatText, restReplies.getReplyText());
                chatMap.put(firstName, restReplies.getReplyingPersonName());
                chatMap.put(chatImage, restReplies.getSenderImage());
                chatMap.put(privateChannel,"/service/person/"+String.valueOf(conversationId));
                chatMessagesHashMapList.add(chatMap);
            }

            chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatList);

            chatMessagesAdapter = new ChatMessagesAdapter(chatMessagesActivity, chatMessagesHashMapList);

            chatList.setAdapter(chatMessagesAdapter);

            chatList.scrollTo(0, chatList.getHeight());

        }
    }
```

So, how should I instruct that the data-set has been changed.. And how does the adapter knows where and how to get the data-set which has changed. Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks a lot... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcast receiver at your adapter and fire a local broadcast with android LocalBroadcast in your push service

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if(intent.getAction().equals("MYREFRESH"))
        {
            notifiyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

In your constructor in adapter register this reciever

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("MYREFRESH");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(broadReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In your push if you get a push notification trigger this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(...) //send any data to your adapter
Intent.setAction("myaction");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: That sounds fancy, unfortunately I have not worked in android for more then 2 weeks. Can you kindly tell me how I can achieve that. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed your answer by formatting. Checking now. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the code you gave, but there are few unknown fields, which I don't know what they are, and I have to process message in PUSH before sending it out, so cannot directly trigger something there. Can you please check this pastebin which contains both classes one below other and tell me where I should make the changes... Pastebin link : http://pastebin.com/7gCCuPuY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96872/discussion-between-prasanna-anbu-and-we-are-borg).

Answer (score 0):

The way to deal with this is using a broadcast or bus pattern. You can use some good bus libraries such as http://square.github.io/otto/ or a [LocalBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

This past answer from me shows how to use the LocalBroadcast system: [Refreshing fragments in FragmentActivity after sync service runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326440/refreshing-fragments-in-fragmentactivity-after-sync-service-runs/20396736#20396736)